# Select elements using nth-child()

Tags: html, css

how to target a `li` which is before/previous element of the  selected or active `li` using css `nth-child()` concept?

```
<ul>
  <li><li>
  <li>i want to select this li</li>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is no `prev` selector until css3. Seems that only in css4. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15503444/863110. You can do this with jquery.

Comment: ok, thanks fro the reply. i will do it jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no previous sibling selector in CSS, there is a next adjacent sibling one though (using the `+` selector):

```css
li.active {
  color: red;
}
li.active + li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>This one can't be selected with pure CSS only...</li>
  <li class="active">This is the active one</li>
  <li>This is adjacent to active</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT - Here's a jQuery way using `prev()` to select the immediately previous sibling:

```js
$("li.active").prev().addClass("prevsibling");
```

```css
li.active {
  color: red;
}
li.prevsibling, li.active + li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>This one has had a class appended via jQuery!</li>
  <li class="active">This is the active one</li>
  <li>This is adjacent to active</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok, then let me do some work around with jquery :), thanks for the reply @David

Comment: @IamSarav there's plenty of ways with JS :-). JS always comes to the resue!

Comment: ha ha :D that's true.. i just wanted to try a simple way if its possible in CSS.

Comment: @IamSarav No worries - I've added a jQuery answer for you too for clarity :-)

Comment: Thats great!! @David. :) thanks a lot

Comment: @IamSarav No problem - be sure to mark an answer as correct if it helps you out - it might help others in the future :)